# I want to remove string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `os`in Python to retrieve a list of files in a folder. Once I get the list, I want to clean up the names of the files and remove the ".pdf" at the end of each file name. What I'm trying, is not working.

```
    path = "C:/....."
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    dirs = pd.DataFrame(data=dirs)
    dirs.replace({".pdf", None}, inplace=True)
    print(dirs, sep="\n")
```

These are an example of the files in my folder
[image]
So basically, I only want to keep the digits of the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.path.splitext()`.

```
dirs = os.path.splitext("/path/to/some/file.pdf")[0])
```

This results in:

```
/path/to/some/file
```